# Ubuntu Crashing/Freezing random on completely new T460P

Tags: 14.04, drivers, crash

So i'm getting quite desperate here.

I bought a brand new T460P. I then tried to install Ubuntu on it(15.10, 16.04, 16.10) and also debian. My problem is that it freezes seemingly random. It's a hard freeze meaning only a hard reset can fix it.
Sometimes there goes a couple of hours and other times it's just minutes. It also happens during the boot sequence(when loading ubuntu).
I haven't run anything else such as windows on it so i don't know how that reacts.

Specs:

- Intel HD 530
- Intel Core I5 6300HQ
- 8GB Ram
- 8260 AC Wireless Dual Band

I've had somewhat success with reproducing the crash by transferring a large file through netcat. It only takes a few seconds to crash.
Using:

> nc -l -p 1234 > out.file

But if it were network related it wouldn't be crashing during boot would it?

I have used all the built in tools to test for hardware defects and also updated the bios, intel-microcodes, i915 drivers.
I have also tried just around every kernel(4.2, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8) with no luck.

I would post some logs but i really can't find anything related to the crash. If you need any logs or anything just reply and i'll post.

Comment: The output of **iotop** command can help you to fix this problem. But it seems that it's a problem with your HDD. if you have an HDD I recommend you to replace it with a new SSD.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put it in the original post. It is an Samsung SSD

Comment: So would you please send the output of  **iotop** ?

Comment: I will send later today when i get back to my personal computer. Should i do something while running iotop or just idle ?

Comment: I think it's better to send it in both idle and when you use netcat